# How to update Facebook status through the Facebook PowerShell module?

Tags: facebook, powershell, facebook-graph-api, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I'm using the [Facebook PowerShell Module](http://facebookpsmodule.codeplex.com/) to connect to my Facebook using PowerShell.

New-FBConnection logs me in successfully. Get-FBConnection fetches results successfully. When I try to update my status with

> New-FbFeed -message "This is a test message."

I get an error as "Error in New-FB Feed: (OAuthException - #200) (#200) The user hasn't authorised the application to perform this action" 
[image]

I checked my Facebook apps setting, I do see the Owner app there. I presume the app has been authorised when we first establish connection with the New-FBConnection. Why am I unable to post a status update? Thanks.

Comment: _“Why am I unable to post a status update?”_ – because it doesn’t have the necessary permission from the user. _“I presume the app has been authorised when […]”_ – don’t “presume”, but _verify_. Log the access token that’s being used somewhere (no, don’t ask me how to do that with the particular tool you’re using), and put it through the FB debug tool to see what permissions it contains.

Comment: It is missing the publish_actions permission. The owner of the module did not update his app. He has to submit it for review which is probably not done.

 I am left with 2 oprions. Either contact the dev to update the app and ps1 script or create my own app and make this work. 

Thanks for your input.